# Specify a character set in HTML imported via Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to create a message in a M365 folder, via Graph (direct http calls, not any kind of managed API). The url is:

```
beta/users/jjmckay912@outlook.com/mailFolders/{id...}/messages
```

For the moment I am using a JSON representation of the message. If the "subject" or other such properties contain UTF-8 characters, they are displayed fine. However I have a HTML message body, which is encoded as iso-8859-2. This is specified in the "META" html tag. Unfortunately Graph does not process this, and the message is incorrectly rendered when viewing. I am not creating this HTML myself, it comes from another system, and I am very reluctant to try and modify it.

Note: if I were to import the message body via MIME (i.e. RFC822 type data) it will work fine. Unfortunately there are problems with that method, in that due to other deficiencies in Graph, I cannot put it in the correct folder.

Note: using the v1.0 endpoint makes no difference.

Is there some way to tell Graph what the character set of the message body should be, or get it to handle the HTML correctly?

Update: below is an example of such an HTML body that will not render correctly.

```
<html><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2"><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
 {font-family:"Cambria Math";
 panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
 {font-family:Calibri;
 panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
 {font-family:Tahoma;
 panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
 {margin:0cm;
 margin-bottom:.0001pt;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
 mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
 {mso-style-priority:99;
 color:#0563C1;
 text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
 {mso-style-priority:99;
 color:#954F72;
 text-decoration:underline;}
span.StylE-mailovZprvy17
 {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
 font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
.MsoChpDefault
 {mso-style-type:export-only;
 font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
 mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
@page WordSection1
 {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
 margin:70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt;}
div.WordSection1
 {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=CS link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72"><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal>Ahoj<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Kouknìte se na <a href="https://bee.my.workfront.com/task/view?ID=5c750f6600b91e16e9aed2a9e8f13fdd">https://bee.my.workfront.com/task/view?ID=5c750f6600b91e16e9aed2a9e8f13fdd</a><o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:24.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma",sans-serif;color:#333333;background:white'>Zápis GDPR dokumentu do DMS<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Je to pøipravené ale aktuálnì nefunguje testovací DMS &#8211; domluvte se s&nbsp;eMan<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Jirka<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p></div></body></html>
```

Update 2:
I have added the property as described, but my results look like this:
[image]

I don't think Graph is interpreting my non-English characters correctly, or changing them to something else. Look at, for example, the phrase in the original HTML "Zápis GDPR".  The character after the Z is lower case 'a' with acute. In the original file that character is represented by 0xE1. I am as certain as I can be that in the JSON that I'm uploading, that character remains 0xE1. That seems to also be the case in your example JSON. However, when I look at the result of the POST, where Graph feeds back the data, what I see is (in hex) c4 8f c5 bc cb 9d. This seems to be the UTF-8 encoding for the weird characters that are displayed. How the heck did that conversion happen?

Comment: Do you have any example of such html body, so we can try it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I've updated the post to include sample html.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you need to specify the correct code page used for message body.

The Graph API doesn't expose any property for messages to specify the code page, but the code page can be set through the [singleValueExtendedProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-post-singlevalueextendedproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

In `singleValueExtendedProperties` you need to specify identifier for the [PidTagInternetCodepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtaginternetcodepage-canonical-property) MAPI property (`Integer 0x3fde`) and the value of the code page for **ISO 8859-2** which is **28592**.

Example for sendMail
POST /v1.0/me/sendMail

```
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "Test",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": "<html><META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-2\"><html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:w=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-2\"><meta name=Generator content=\"Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)\"><style></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:shapedefaults v:ext=\"edit\" spidmax=\"1026\" /></xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:shapelayout v:ext=\"edit\"><o:idmap v:ext=\"edit\" data=\"1\" /></o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=CS link=\"#0563C1\" vlink=\"#954F72\"><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal>Ahoj<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Kouknìte se na <a href=\"https://bee.my.workfront.com/task/view?ID=5c750f6600b91e16e9aed2a9e8f13fdd\">https://bee.my.workfront.com/task/view?ID=5c750f6600b91e16e9aed2a9e8f13fdd</a><o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><span>Zápis GDPR dokumentu do DMS<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Je to pøipravené ale aktuálnì nefunguje testovací DMS &#8211; domluvte se s&nbsp;eMan<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Jirka<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p></div></body></html>"
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "john.doe@contoso.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
            {
                "id": "Integer 0x3fde",
                "value": "28592"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comments, this looks like it should be the answer, but so far I've not had any luck.  The problem seems to be that Graph is changing my non-English characters to something else.  I've explained more in an update to my post.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: I should probably point out that I am not using the sendMail endpoint, rather "mailFolders/{folderid}/messages".  I've tried both 1.0 and beta versions, no difference.

Comment: @JeffMcKay works fine for me also for the endpoint POST mailFolders/{folderid}/messages. What do you specify in JSON body in a request? Do you use any Graph API SDK? Probably there is some difference in between your JSON body and my attempt

Comment: I think maybe one or both of us is being confused by character transformations made by Windows copy/paste, or the editors we use.  I tried copy/paste of your json above into my editor and saved it.  Then substituted that into what I upload to Graph.  Characters worked fine.  Using a binary editor, I can see that the 'a' acute in what works is encoded as xC3 xA1 (UTF-8) while what fails is xE1 (ISO-8859-2).  So I still think that Graph is failing to handle non-UTF8 characters correctly, but I'll keep looking at this.  I really don't want to convert my HTML code in any way.

Comment: Here's another head scratcher.  I tried escaping any character > x7F by changing it to \u00XX where XX is the 2 digit hex code. If I do that for ONLY xE1, and REMOVE any other characters > x7F, it works to display the 'a' acute correctly.  But if I do that for any other character, such as xEC (lower 'e' with caron) then all non-English chars are messed up, including xE1.  Totally screwy.  It would be nice if Graph allowed me to base64 encode the whole html string, like EWS does, but I don't see any documentation for that.